# Why did TeXstudio suddenly highlight some commands with red background?

Tags: errors, texstudio, highlighting

I tried to compile from a .tex file included by master. TeXstudio didn't infere that master.tex, which was also open in Texstudio was the master. I received a lot of error messages, and as a result, TeXstudio now highlights almost every command like this:
[image]

I have tried restarting TeXstudio and deleting all the temporary files generated while compiling (log files, etc.) without success.

Comment: The master.tex does look normal still? Could you provide me with some really minimal examples of master.tex and proofwhaterver.tex? I will try it on my system then.

Comment: Which error messages?

Comment: Master.tex has the same highlighting issue now. The error messages were just standard errors when trying to compile a non-master document. "Missing \begin{document}" or something. It seems like some kind of error highlighting mode has been enabled.

Comment: If I hover over the red highlights, it says "Unrecognized command". But the command is recognized, since I can compile easily. It just looks like the highlights still remain from when I compiled from the non-master document.

Comment: I can remove highlights by toggling the checkbox in Options / Configure TeXstudio / Editor / Inline Checking / Syntax. It doesn't solve the problem however. I still want to highlight syntax errors, but not from commands that actually exist.

Comment: Well, please make it simple for us. Remove all the subfiles, just give us a minimalistic `master.tex` (code, not photo) and tell us, which command is highlighted as "unrecognized command". If there is some compilation error, this is another topic. Kick that out of your question or be more specific if you think, both things are related to each other.

Comment: Guessing from what I see in your screen-shot, it looks as if you should toggle `Options|Configure TeXstudio|Completion|Permanently activated completion lists|latex-mathsymbols.cwl`. Have you added `\usepackage{mathtools}` or `\usepackage{amsmath}` into your preamble of `master.tex`. That should fix your `\begin{align*}`

Comment: \usepackage{amsmath} will fulfill your purpose.

Answer (score 7):

As some people have commented on, the red highlighting is part of teXstudios syntax highlighting and completion option.

If your document compiles correctly, then it is not a problem with your code and a simple solution is simply to open `Options->Configure TeXstudio->Completion` and then tick on your most frequently used packages (`amsmath, mathtools`, etc.).

TeXstudio should recognize them automatically, but it has trouble recognizing packages if they are loaded in the same command (e.g. `\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}`) or via a separate preamble file that is loaded using `\input{preamble.file}`. hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The highlighting is part of the syntax checking in TeXstudio. Your file is part of a multi-file document and depending on the complexity of your document you may need to help TeXstudio a little to recognize that.

For details see [FAQ: Does TeXstudio support projects i.e. multi-file documents](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#does-texstudio-support-projects-ie-mutli-file-documents)